# group_by() and summarise() calculates sd but returns NA for mean

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation from a dataframe grouped by time and certain variables.

There is no problem when I perform the following code with a made-up data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

experiment <- c("ex1","ex1","ex1","ex1","ex1","ex1","ex1","ex1","ex2","ex2","ex2","ex2","ex2","ex2","ex2","ex2")
time <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2")  
bottle <- c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4")
var1 <- runif(16, min=2, max=50)
var2 <- runif(16, min=2, max=50)
var3 <- runif(16, min=2, max=50)
df <- data.frame(experiment,time,bottle,var1,var2,var3)

df_melt <- melt(df, id = c("experiment", "time","bottle"))

df_avg <- df_melt %>% 
  filter(experiment %in% c("ex2")) %>%
  filter(bottle %in% c(1,2,3)) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("var1","var2")) %>%  
  group_by(time, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd= sd(value))
```

The above gives me the mean and sd no problem.

However, when I perform the exact same code but using my real data, it calculates the standard deviation but return all NA for mean. I know sharing data file is not encouraged on Stack Overflow, but I am really spinning my wheels here.

Here is my [data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTHr_6yxHi1YTuXRJqiJZr54HaU9gMg6/view?usp=sharing), and the code is the following:

```
data <- read.csv("path to data file",fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
data_melted <- melt(data, id = c("Experiment", "Time", "Bottle"))

data_avg <- data_melted %>% 
  filter(Experiment %in% c("Vienn_U-A")) %>%
  filter(Bottle %in% c(1,2,4,5)) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("NH4","NO2","Urea")) %>%  
  group_by(Time, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd= sd(value))
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
> data_avg
# A tibble: 54 x 4
# Groups:   Time [18]
    Time variable  mean     sd
   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0   NH4         NA  0.750
 2   0   Urea        NA 10.4  
 3   0   NO2         NA  0.243
 4  24.6 NH4         NA  0.539
 5  24.6 Urea        NA  8.87 
 6  24.6 NO2         NA  0.590
 7  48.2 NH4         NA  0.477
 8  48.2 Urea        NA  8.97 
 9  48.2 NO2         NA  1.21 
10  77.9 NH4         NA  0.899
# ... with 44 more rows
```

Why does it calculate the sd, but returns NA for mean? Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new link, the issue is how one of the column types were changed while reading with `read.csv` and not in `read_excel` i.e. column 'TN' is `character` class in `read.csv` whereas it is `numeric`

```
> data <- read.csv("CSV for plotting.csv", na.strings = "")
> str(data)
'data.frame':   292 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Experiment: chr  "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" ...
 $ Time      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Bottle    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ NH4       : num  550 551 546 555 551 ...
 $ Urea      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NO2       : num  18.6 18.3 18.6 18.1 18.9 ...
 $ NO3       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Ln.NO2    : num  2.92 2.91 2.92 2.9 2.94 ...
 $ TN        : chr  "568.5714286" "569" "564.2857143" "573.1428571" ...
```

This is partly due to some elements that are read as `#REF`

```
[81] "913.8095238" "870.1428571" "914.1190476" "946.9761905" "903.5238095" "962.6428571" "965.2619048" "982.3809524" "909.1904762" "#REF!"
```

and the same line is `NA` while reading with `read_excel`

```
[85]  903.5238  962.6429  965.2619  982.3810  909.1905        NA
```

This causes major problems with `melt` as the columns specified are `"Experiment", "Time","Bottle"` and it implies that the other column when `melt`ed will have a single type, but because it is `character` in one class, the whole column converted to `character` class

```
> str(data_melted)
'data.frame':   1752 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Experiment: chr  "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" ...
 $ Time      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Bottle    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 6 levels "NH4","Urea","NO2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : chr  "550" "550.7142857" "545.7142857" "555" ...
```

i.e. the `value` column is the one of interest here, which is now a different class than expected for `mean` which is not a problem for `sd` as it gets converted

```
> sd(c("15", "25", "35"))
[1] 10
>  sd(as.numeric(c("15", "25", "35"))) # same output
[1] 10
> mean(c("15", "25", "35"))
[1] NA
```

The reason is that according to the documentation of `?sd`

> x- a numeric vector or an R object but not a factor coercible to numeric by as.double(x).

i.e. it is converting internally by `as.double` and the function confirms it

```
> sd
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
    na.rm = na.rm))
```

`melt` does a type conversion without throwing error.  Suppose, if we use `pivot_longer` (from `tidyr`) it would raise an error and we would know the issue

```
> tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = NH4:TN)
Error: Can't combine `NH4` <double> and `TN` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

---

Within the context of reading with `read.csv` an option will be to specify the `#REF` as `NA` elements

```
> data <- read.csv("CSV for plotting.csv", na.strings = c("", "#REF!"))
> str(data)
'data.frame':   292 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Experiment: chr  "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" ...
 $ Time      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Bottle    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ NH4       : num  550 551 546 555 551 ...
 $ Urea      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NO2       : num  18.6 18.3 18.6 18.1 18.9 ...
 $ NO3       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Ln.NO2    : num  2.92 2.91 2.92 2.9 2.94 ...
 $ TN        : num  569 569 564 573 570 ...
```

Now, the `melt` would work correctly

```
> data_melted <- melt(data, id = c("Experiment", "Time","Bottle"))
> str(data_melted)
'data.frame':   1752 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Experiment: chr  "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" "Vienn_A-U" ...
 $ Time      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Bottle    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 6 levels "NH4","Urea","NO2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value     : num  550 551 546 555 551 ...
```

So would the `mean`

```
> data_avg <- data_melted %>% 
+   filter(Experiment %in% c("Vienn_U-A")) %>%
+   filter(Bottle %in% c(1,2,4,5)) %>% 
+   filter(variable %in% c("NH4","NO2","Urea")) %>%  
+   group_by(Time, variable) %>%
+   summarise(mean = mean(value), sd= sd(value)) 
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Time'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
> data_avg
# A tibble: 54 × 4
# Groups:   Time [18]
    Time variable   mean     sd
   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0   NH4        4.77  0.750
 2   0   Urea     281.   10.4  
 3   0   NO2       12.3   0.243
 4  24.6 NH4        9.11  0.539
 5  24.6 Urea     275.    8.87 
 6  24.6 NO2       17.8   0.590
 7  48.2 NH4       13.6   0.477
 8  48.2 Urea     268.    8.97 
 9  48.2 NO2       27.9   1.21 
10  77.9 NH4        8.75  0.899
# … with 44 more rows
```

---

If there are `NA` values, consider using `na.rm = TRUE` in the `mean` and `sd`.  By default, those are set as `FALSE`.  In case, the `mean` from `base` is masked, use the `::`.  Also, the original link seems to be excel file.  So, read the file with `read_excel`

```
library(dplyr)
data_avg <- data_melted %>% 
  filter(Experiment %in% c("Vienn_U-A")) %>%
  filter(Bottle %in% c(1,2,4,5)) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("NH4","NO2","Urea")) %>%  
  group_by(Time, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = base::mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), sd= sd(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
> data_avg
# A tibble: 54 × 4
# Groups:   Time [18]
    Time variable   mean     sd
   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0   NH4        4.77  0.750
 2   0   Urea     281.   10.4  
 3   0   NO2       12.3   0.243
 4  24.6 NH4        9.11  0.539
 5  24.6 Urea     275.    8.87 
 6  24.6 NO2       17.8   0.590
 7  48.2 NH4       13.6   0.477
 8  48.2 Urea     268.    8.97 
 9  48.2 NO2       27.9   1.21 
10  77.9 NH4        8.75  0.899
# … with 44 more rows
```

---

The file in the link shows `excel` data.  It may be better to read with packages that read the excel data

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("CSV for plotting.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by akrun's answer, I was able to resolve this by working with `.xlsx` file and avoiding `.csv` file. It was not a problem with having `NA` values.

Here is the [data file in .xlsx format](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlHK-h6IM1EWlp1XPSI7Ba5mxNA2TQ?e=sAy5yU), and the following code worked:

```
data <- read_excel("CSV for plotting.xlsx") #following akrun's suggestion 
data_melted <- melt(data, id = c("Experiment", "Time","Bottle"))
data_avg <- data_melted %>% 
  filter(Experiment %in% c("Vienn_U-A")) %>%
  filter(Bottle %in% c(1,2,4,5)) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("NH4","NO2","Urea")) %>%  
  group_by(Time, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd= sd(value))
```

Output with the correct `mean` values:

```
    Time variable   mean     sd
   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0   NH4        4.77  0.750
 2   0   Urea     281.   10.4  
 3   0   NO2       12.3   0.243
 4  24.6 NH4        9.11  0.539
 5  24.6 Urea     275.    8.87 
 6  24.6 NO2       17.8   0.590
 7  48.2 NH4       13.6   0.477
 8  48.2 Urea     268.    8.97 
 9  48.2 NO2       27.9   1.21 
10  77.9 NH4        8.75  0.899
# ... with 44 more rows
```

As mentioned above, working with `.csv` file still gives the problem of returning NA for the `mean`.

Here is the same [data file but in .csv format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTHr_6yxHi1YTuXRJqiJZr54HaU9gMg6/view?usp=sharing)

```
data <- read.csv("CSV for plotting.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
data_melted <- melt(data, id = c("Experiment", "Time","Bottle"))
data_avg <- data_melted %>% 
  filter(Experiment %in% c("Vienn_U-A")) %>%
  filter(Bottle %in% c(1,2,4,5)) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("NH4","NO2","Urea")) %>%  
  group_by(Time, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd= sd(value))
```

Output with `NA` for the `mean` but not `sd`:

```
 Time variable  mean     sd
   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0   NH4         NA  0.750
 2   0   Urea        NA 10.4  
 3   0   NO2         NA  0.243
 4  24.6 NH4         NA  0.539
 5  24.6 Urea        NA  8.87 
 6  24.6 NO2         NA  0.590
 7  48.2 NH4         NA  0.477
 8  48.2 Urea        NA  8.97 
 9  48.2 NO2         NA  1.21 
10  77.9 NH4         NA  0.899
# ... with 44 more rows
```

It still baffles me why `.csv` file has this problem, but at least there is a solution.

Comment: I updated the link where I had ```data file but in .csv format```. Can you try again?